# Download something using javascript not works inside In-App browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, inappbrowser, vcf-vcard

I have a button inside a web app that when the user clicks downloads a .vcf file inside the device. But when someone opens it inside an in-app browser that button stops working. I have tried everywhere else it works perfectly fine there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're welcome, but it's not clear how anybody can help with the information provided.

Comment: @DaveNewton here is the link https://stackdigitalcard.com/amin-OBu8 you can share it with yourself on LinkedIn and when you will click on it you will see a web page with a download contact button. When you will click on it, it will do nothing but when you open the same link on the normal browser that button will work fine. Now it works fine on all browsers and not works inside in-app browsers specifically on some Iphones. I am using downloadjs npm package for downloading purposes.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.